# PHPIniDir not supported in Apache 2.4?

Tags: php, httpd.conf, apache2.4

4 with PHP as an so module in my mac os El Capitan.
I wanted to change the location of the php.ini file inside the httpd.conf file, and I used the PHPIniDir directive, but when i looked at phpinfo.php, i noticed the location was still /etc folder. I looked in the Apache 2.4 documentation and I noticed that there is no PHPIniDir directive listed. Am I wrong, and indeed it is still supported, or it is in fact not anymore?

thanks

-malena

Comment: `PHPIniDir` does affect only the php-module loaded with `LoadModule`.

Comment: I am working on Apache2.4 i have not noticed this directory, i change routes or any directory in `php.ini`